# Secure PFFile by locking access via url (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, security, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I programmed an ios app using the parse sdk. I save very sensitive data as a PFFILE on my server concerning my user.
I recognized that anybody can access the file through its url (example.com/bdjdjddbska jeiyj(...)ek.pdf) and now I’m scared about the data.
Does parse have a built-in Security Solution in order to keep strangers away from those files or do I have to set up some cloud code?
Or are the files secure enough as long as nobody gets the link?
I would appreciate an answer!